# Physical installed RAM is 6GB, but 4GB only is used by Ubuntu 22.04 as well as by Windows 7

Tags: hardware, ram, bios

My machine has 6GB of physical installed RAM 2x2GB + 2x1GB, but 4GB only is available by Ubuntu 22.04 as well as by Windows 7.
launching dmidecode I can see:
Memory Controller Information
...
Maximum Memory Module Size: 1024 MB
Maximum Total Memory Size: 4096 MB
...
**is this meaning that each 2048MB module will be downsized to 1024MB ?**

Actual BIOS (No newer BIOS is available):
Vendor: Phoenix Technologies, LTD
Version:  5.09
Release Date: 01/11/2007 ...

Actual Motherboard:
Manufacturer: ASUSTek Computer INC.
Product Name: LEONITE
Version: 5.00
Serial Number: MS1C72S01900311 ...
[image: @karel info]

Comment: It is typical that GPU is using 2 MB RAM. It is not related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

The information about your computer's memory that appears in Settings app -> *About* confirms that 6GB of RAM is available to be used by Ubuntu. I predict that running the `neofetch` command from the terminal would show the same amount of memory that appears in the Settings app as well as showing the amount of memory that is currently being used.

If you run RAM with mismatched specs, it will still run, but at the common lowest denominator (lowest frequency, higher latency, etc.). RAM is normally installed in matching sets to prevent this from happening.